# HTML (5ish): How to semantically interpose a gallery in an article

Tags: html, semantics, article

Typical article: I want to display an article that is primarily text with a few embedded images or media files.

Typical Gallery: I also want to display an image gallery that is (loosely) related to the topic of the article. For the purpose of this question, let's suppose that the gallery is a 20 item flickr search on key words that are used in the article.

The train wreck: The mini-gallery should cut the article right after the lead, and the article should continue below the mini-gallery.

I was hammering out the html like so:

```
<div id="lead">yadda</div>
<div id="mini-gallery">img's</div>
<div id="paras">yadda</div>
```

When all the recent html5 excitement began telling me, *"This is just wrong, what you are doing!"* (to quote Heroku from Speed Racer).

So.. after some searching... the question persists... is there a "follow from" DOM object or what?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the semantic answer(?):

```
<article id="feature">
    <header>Article Title and whatnot</header>
    <section id="lead">Lion eats Youtube persona...</section>
    <aside id="mini-gallery">img's</aside>
    <section id="paras">grisly details, twitter trending of said details, etc...</section>
</article>
```

The problem is that this aside is sort of an "inside" and as I understand it, an aside should not be in the article to which it is marginally relevant...

Anyway, this article: http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/ seems to assert that an aside can be embedded in an article but not if it is just tangentially associated. So, I am thinking there is a better option.

Comment: yeah, on that same page (html5doc linked above) there is a comment here: http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/#comment-2251 which, combined with the intent of a later comment, http://html5doctor.com/aside-revisited/#comment-5799 , gives what I see as a workable answer. Someone write this up nicely (or improve on it) and I'll accept the answer ;)